# Dot overlaps application name in app drawer (20.04)

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell

[image]

As you can see in the attatched image, the dot which shows that dconf editor is open overlaps the label. This does not happen for the apps in folders like office utilities etc. How do I stop this from happening?

If a solution to shift the dot below the label is not available, can I just turn off the dot? Its quite unnecessary.

Comment: @UnKNOWn what does that mean? Sorry im not really familiar with the terms.

Comment: I see the default ones only: Adwaita, Yaru, HighContrast. I havent installed any external themes.

Comment: I dont think so, I have dash to panel.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I tried turning of all other extensions too, the problem persists.

Comment: No the width is the same.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time

Comment: How do i do that? I know how to install user themes, but how do i make the dot disappear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116130/discussion-between-dnaik-and-unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have provided a workaround to hide the dot though shifting the dot is possible but takes more time from my side.

Download the `dot.zip` file from this  [git-hub-link.](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/LinkOnly/tree/main)

Install the extension from the downloaded `dot.zip` file.
Enable the extension and refresh the gnome-shell or logout/login

Dot should disappear now.

[image]

Brave and Files apps are running, notice there is not dot in AllApps.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thanks a lot.